# maximum Thread count in RMI server side

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, rmi, remoteobject

if number of java clients are 2000 and if they call remote method
how many threads are executed in RMI server side?

Is there any maximum limit of the number of Threads in RMI serverside?

Comment: Yes, the limit is set in the server properties, check the server documentation, what is the thread pool size for the serving of incoming requests.

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki No, there is no maximum by default. You can impose one via a system property, from Java 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if number of java clients are 2000 and if they call remote method how many threads are executed in RMI server side?

Up to 2000.

> Is there any maximum limit of the number of Threads in RMI serverside?

No. There is no limit specified. Specific implementations may have such limits, but the Sun/Oracle implementation isn't one of them. You can *set* a maximum, in the Sun/Oracle JRE, via [`sun.rmi.transport.tcp.maxConnectionThreads`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/sunrmiproperties.html), but by default there isn't one.

Comment: thanks. if no of clients will increase from 2000 to 5000 or even more, then we know that Thread consumes memory in heap, then is there any OutOfMemory Exceptions happens? if so is this exception is catched in RMI client program?

Comment: It *should* manifest itself at the client as a `ServerError` with a cause of `OutOfMemoryError`.